# How to show/hide UIPopoverController using a single button with a single action method

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller

The following method is associated with a nav bar button. When the button is pressed, it shows a `UIPopoverController`

```
- (IBAction) showTablePopUp:(id) sender {

if (self.tablesPopoverController == nil) {

    TablesPopOverViewController *tables = [[TablesPopOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TablesPopOverViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tables]; 

    popover.delegate = self;
    popover.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(280.0, 327.0);
    [tables release];

    self.tablesPopoverController = popover;
    [popover release];
}

[self.tablesPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


}
```

What I want to do is hiding the popover when the button is pressed the second time:

1. Click - show popover
2. Click - hide popover

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
- (IBAction) showTablePopUp:(id) sender {
    if (self.tablesPopoverController == nil) {

        TablesPopOverViewController *tables = [[TablesPopOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TablesPopOverViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tables]; 

        popover.delegate = self;
        popover.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(280.0, 327.0);
        [tables release];

        self.tablesPopoverController = popover;

        [self.tablesPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    } else {
        [self.tablesPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated: YES];
        self.tablesPopeverController = nil;
    }
}
```