# Load a nib in second View

Tags: objective-c, ios, frame, subview, nib

[image]I have a Problem to load some nibs in a view which is in another view.
I want to load this nibs like frames, do you have some interesting tips for me?
Thanks for help
Simon

---

`//.h:
PopOverView *popView;`

`//.m:`

`- (void)viewDidLoad`

`{`

`[super viewDidLoad];`

```
`popView = [[PopOverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopOverView" bundle:nil];`
```

`}`

`-(IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender`
`{`

`[self.view addSubView:popView.view];`

`}`

He Doesnt know PopOverView. I dont want to PopOver I want to load another view into the grey sector. on the left side you have a Control Table and if you click on it you load will a site. like in html a new Frame. Error news: Use of undeclared identifier 'PopOverView'

Comment: '//.h:
PopOverView *popView;'
//.m
popView = [[PopOverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopOverView" bundle:nil];

-(IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.view addSubView:popView.view];
}'
He Doesnt know PopOverView.
I dont want to PopOver I want to load another view into the grey sector. on the left side you have a Control Table and if you click on it you load will a site. like in html a new Frame.

Error news: Use of undeclared identifier 'PopOverView'

Comment: please edit your question to add further details (instead of posting code in comments or answers)

Comment: I did it sorry I am very new in this forum.

Comment: no problem, we all needed to learn :-)

Comment: create UIView in place of UIViewcontroller and use following line of code 
UIView *view =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SubViewController" 
                              owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0]; [self.view addSubview:view];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838154/how-to-show-hide-uipopovercontroller-using-a-single-button-with-a-single-action

Comment: I test it and it works without [self.view addSubview:view];, but not correct it loads on the whole screen not only on the small view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below codes.PopOverView is the subclass of UIViewController.

```
PopOverView *popView = [[PopOverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopOverView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubView:popView.view];
```

Comment: I can't find some information about PopOverView in the iPad programming, sorry, I uploaded a screenshot here you can see my design i want on frist to change the sector "label" its another view which I put inside that

Comment: Do you understand my Question?

Comment: 1)PopOverView subclass of UIViewController you have to create.2) You have to set the frame/bound of popView according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am note sure that you understand me. Maybe I have to explain it again or I understand you and so I am very sorry.

I have a View in this view i created a second view a smaller view with on the right side a tableview. Now I will load with one click on a special row, in the smaller view a "nib". On the Photo upside you see my Objects.
I linked a UIView with the smaller View and for testing I created a Button to load a test nib, it still works, but he loads the whole site not only the small view(the grey one in the Photo)